# 2012 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Well, Super User's *epic* second [moderator election](https://superuser.com/election/2) has come to an end. Our winners are:

[image: Daniel Beck] [image: Oliver Salzburg] [image: slhck]

Please give them a warm welcome, and hearty thanks and congratulations for volunteering!

Comment: Where's the 4th candidate? :P

Comment: Hey look! I just found my Question of the Week for next week :P

Comment: Nice! and these three are the one who I voted for! Congratulations for three of you :D

Comment: Congratulations for three of you...

Comment: Heartly congrats **Daniel**, **Oliver** and **Slhck**.

Answer (score 5):

Really congrats to them from the core of my heart. All three were my choices - however there was a fight between Oliver and KronoS and in this fight Oliver won.

All three have made good contributions to the Super User community with a very humble attitude. I know slhck and Oliver well but have not had the chance to have a conversation with Daniel. They are all very active on this site and it's why they have been chosen as moderators.

Hopefully they will all do the job better than before since slhck was doing moderation related activities anyway.